# How to inject data into Angular2 component created from a router?

Tags: components, router, angular

I'm currently trying to build an Angular2 prototype (based on alpha44) of our Angular1 app (pretty complex one) and I'm trying to find the best model/data architecture when using routes and child routes.

In my example, from a child component created from a route, I want to access a property of the parent component (hosting the `router-outlet`).

But when you create a component from a `router-outlet`,  you cannot use `@Input` and `@Output` anymore.
So what is the best practice to inject some data/properties, except basic `routeParams` and static `routeData`?

How do you communicate with the parent component without too much coupling?

Comment: Look at [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4452). AFAIK now the only way to communicate with component from `router-outlet` is by using DI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RouteData` in order to pass data into routes. See [here](http://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/) and [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/RouteData-class.html). I'm still missing the part of initialising this data obj from the component (see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289761/angular-2-equivalent-to-router-resolve-data-for-new-router) regarding)

Answer (score 2):

A shared service can be used with components added by the router. For details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

`data` support also was added to the new router in RC.4. For details see [How do I pass data in Angular 2 components while using Routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-in-angular-2-components-while-using-routing)

[Angular 2 - equivalent to router resolve data for new router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289761/angular-2-equivalent-to-router-resolve-data-for-new-router/38138019#38138019) might also be related.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass (inject) data from child component inside Router Outlet to Parent component with Subject,Observable. You can found my solution in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2qJxfi7370).

See the code on GitHub: https://github.com/tabvn/angular-blog