# Load component with data dependant on form submission

Tags: angular

I have an application where the user fills in a form.

Currently, when the user submits the form, a GET request is sent to the server. The server responds with all the data that matches the user's form criteria. A new component is then loaded.

**Code**

```
this.formService.getMyData()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/showMyData');
            }
        );
```

I'm not doing anything with the data received. I need a way to pass the data to the new component. Does anyone know how that is done?

**Example of what I'm looking for**

- I fill in a form with the fields 'location' and 'name'.
- I submit the form.
- New component is loaded with a list of all the people who match the location and name I entered previously.

Thanks.

Comment: There are a number of ways you can do this.  

1. Router Params 

2. Shared Service

3. @Inputs with child component

Comment: Like domfx stated... and check this one out: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html :)

Comment: Thanks, I will check these out guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this post [Angular2 using @Inputs with <router-outlet>s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363792/angular2-using-inputs-with-router-outlets)

Also consider just passing the needed parameters from your parent component to your child component through router data and doing the call `this.formService.getMyData()` in the child component since that's the one who needs it