# How to Input data to router-outlet

Tags: angular

I'm trying to send a `@Input` decorator trough a `<router-outlet>`, but can't seem to get the data in the child components, here's what I'm doing:

```
<!--parent route calls the outlet -->
<router-outlet [unit]="unit?.unit"></router-outlet>
```

```
// child route input decorator
export class ClassRoomComponent OnInit {

  @Input() unit: string;
```

```
// router module
...

  path: 'unidade/:unit',
    component: UnitComponent,
    children: [
     {
       path: 'turma/:classroom',
       component: ClassroomComponent,
     }
    ]
  },
```

cosole.log returns me `undefined` tought, why can't I send thata this way?

Comment: You probably need to use route params instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363792/angular2-using-inputs-with-router-outlets or you need to add this data to a service when that `unit?.unit` becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is bind data to the component that is rendered within the `<router-outlet>`.

But what you are actually doing in this case is trying to bind your property to the `<router-outlet>` directive. This won't work - it doesn't automatically transfer your binding to the child component.

You need to pass the data in a different way instead. Try using a service, using route params, or pre-fetching component data using resolve: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data