# How do I pass specific bindings to ng-outlet components brought in by the component router in Angular 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, components, router

I'd like to be able to pass parameters to child components brought in with ng-outlet. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Here's an example of my component bindings:

```
app.component('profile', {
  bindings: {
    section: '=',
    currentUser: '<'
  },
...
```

Normally I'd invoke this like so:

```
<profile section="$ctrl.bio" current-user="$ctrl.selectedUser"></profile>
```

But instead I have this:

```
<ng-outlet></ng-outlet>
```

And a router that passes the profile in.

```
 $routeConfig: [
        { path: '/Profile/:id', name: 'Profile', component: 'profile' }]
```

So how the blazes do I pass other essential bindings, perhaps bindings that can't be encoded into the URL, to this component??

Thanks, help is very much appreciated

**EDIT: I've been asked to provide a more specific example of what I'd like to do.**

I thought the conceptual issue was fairly clear, but here's a particular case where passing route parameters is clearly insufficient. Say at my App component level I have an event callback function, onDeleteItem(id)

How do I replicate

```
bindings: {
    onDeleteItem: "&"
}

...

<some-component on-delete-item="$ctrl.onDeleteItem(id)"></some-component>
```

with an ng-outlet?

Comment: can you make an example showing what you would like to be able to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked on the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router#access-to-the-current-router) and saw this for one of the components used in the router

> `bindings: { $router: '<' }`

So I was thinking well if that binding can get filled in, then why can't we pass data for the other bindings, but I looked through the source of the component router, and I actually don't see a way to pass data that way.  This is because here it looks like it's [specially handling passing in the $router](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular1_router/src/ng_outlet.ts#L112), but I don't think the template is modified after that:

```
activate(instruction) {
    ...
    this.controller.$$template = '<' + dashCase(componentName) + ' $router="::$$router"></' + dashCase(componentName) + '>';
    ...
};
```

I will say though, you are supposed to be able to pass data through to the component using

```
$routeConfig: [
    { path: '/Profile/:id', name: 'Profile', component: 'profile', data: { item1: 'item1'} }]
```

and then injecting [RouteData](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteData-class.html) in the constructor of the component, but I think this is only in angular 2, because I didn't see implementation for it the in the angular 1 router.

So based on the research I've done, I don't think you can, or it's difficult. Also, related: [How to inject data into Angular2 component created from a router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33308340) and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4452

Answer (score 5):

Even through ngOutlet, you can use the require argument like specified here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component to require a parent component. This way, you can communicate with the parent component from the child component (even so the parent component calls the child component through ngOutlet). This enables the communication from child => parent. Regarding parent => child, you could still use the same technic, even if it feels a bit awkward (you call the parent from the child to get what you need...). Maybe something more standard already exists, or will be implemented soon.

Comment: This is actually a really nice workaround--yeah. By requiring the parent, all the bindings you would have liked to have been passed will be accessible on the parent controller.