# How do I pass data to Angular routed components?

Tags: angular, typescript

In one of my Angular 2 routes's templates (**FirstComponent**) I have a button

**first.component.html**

```
<div class="button" click="routeWithData()">Pass data and route</div>
```

My **goal** is to achieve:

> Button click -> route to another component while preserving data and without using the other component as a directive.

This is what I tried...

**1ST APPROACH**

In the same view I am storing collecting same data based on user interaction.

**first.component.ts**

```
export class FirstComponent {
     constructor(private _router: Router) { }

     property1: number;
     property2: string;
     property3: TypeXY; // this a class, not a primitive type

    // here some class methods set the properties above

    // DOM events
    routeWithData(){
         // here route
    }
}
```

Normally I'd route to **SecondComponent** by

```
 this._router.navigate(['SecondComponent']);
```

eventually passing the data by

```
 this._router.navigate(['SecondComponent', {p1: this.property1, p2: property2 }]);
```

whereas the definition of the link with parameters would be

```
@RouteConfig([
      // ...
      { path: '/SecondComponent/:p1:p2', name: 'SecondComponent', component: SecondComponent} 
)]
```

The issue with this approach is that I guess **I can't pass complex data** (e.g. an **object** like property3) in-url;

**2ND APPROACH**

An alternative would be including SecondComponent as **directive** in FirstComponent.

```
  <SecondComponent [p3]="property3"></SecondComponent>
```

However I want to **route** to that component, not include it!

**3RD APPROACH**

The most viable solution I see here would be to use a **Service** (e.g. FirstComponentService) to

- **store** the data (_firstComponentService.storeData()) on routeWithData() in FirstComponent
- **retrieve** the data (_firstComponentService.retrieveData()) in **ngOnInit()** in **SecondComponent**

While this approach seems perfectly viable, I wonder whether this is the easiest / most elegant way to achieve the goal.

In general I'd like to know whether I'm missing other **potential approaches** to pass the data between components, particularly **with the less possible amount of code**

Comment: thanks @Prashobh. `Pass data using Query Parameters` is what i was looking for. your [link](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/12/3-simple-ways-to-share-data-through.html) saved my day.

Comment: Angular 7.2 has now new feature to pass data between routes using `state` check the [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/27198) for more details. Some useful information [here](https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb)

Comment: @Prashobh Thanks a lot. The link which you have shared is very useful

Comment: Working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69420764/7186739

Comment: Routing is a complex feature in Angular and definitely worth learning! Here you may find interesting details about passing data via the routing:
https://indepth.dev/tutorials/angular/indepth-guide-to-passing-data-via-routing
This guide goes through various techniques about using static data in routing definition and dynamic data (state) during specific navigation.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

**Update 4.0.0**

See Angular [Angular Router - Fetch data before navigating](https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating) for more details.

**Original**

Using a service is the way to go. In route params you should only pass data that you want to be reflected in the browser URL bar.

See Angular [Angular Cookbook Component Communication - Bidirectional Service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

The router shipped with RC.4 re-introduces `data`

```ts
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

```ts
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'heroes', component: HeroDetailComponent, data: {some_data: 'some value'}}
];
```

```ts
class HeroDetailComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .data
      .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

See also the [Plunker](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9757#issuecomment-229847781).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had a look at the docs. Can you please clarify when I should opt for observables and when just set attributes using a set/get method in the service?

Comment: Observables allow interested components to subscribe to changes. With properties you need to poll (`{{myService.someProp}}` is recognized and updated by Angulars change detection though). If you want to switch to the way more performant `OnPush` change detection strategy `Observables` have a strong advantage because then your code depends on being notified about changes so your code can invoke change detection.

Comment: Is this answer still valid for Angular 2.1.0 ?

Comment: RC.4 router data is only for static data. You can not send different data to the same route it always has to be the same data am I wrong?

Comment: If you use a resolver, then you get the data the resolver returns.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure the data has been stored before retrieving it? For example in the OP situation, not loading `SecondComponent` until a good response from the store data has been received. Otherwise `SecondComponent` would be empty

Comment: I guess it would be better to create a new question with more details (some code). I don't really get what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am a bit confused... i have 3 components which use same data but how can i update the data in all 3 components if the data is changed by 1 of the 3 components... 1 is app component 1 is popup component which is inside app component..i can exchange data thr.. i can pass data to router-outlet by using service but if after passing data..the data is changed by popup component..it wont change in router-outlet component..how can i update data thr??

Comment: @HimanshuBansal please create a new question with the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish

Comment: Is it possible to pass data during navigate instead of in the router as described in this answer? Example, this.router.navigate(['/apply', res.loanApplicationId, data{}]);

Comment: No, use a shared service for this use case.

Comment: How to get that 'some value'.  getting an array in this.sub

Comment: @user630209 sorry, I don't understand the question. I'd suggest you create a new question that contains your code and more details about what you try to accomplish.

Comment: In Angular 5, anyway, you should be able to ... 
`ngOnInit() {
  this.myVar = this.route.snapshot.data['some_data'];
}`

Comment: how to pass dynamic json?

Comment: @bhaumikshah use a shared service.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is there any example for reference?

Comment: Injecting a service is an effective hack that dates back to the first release of the framework and continues to this day.  This approach also stinks to high heaven.  Components should not be wired for eternity to services.  That's what @input is designed for.

Comment: @RickO'Shea that's clearly wrong. Services can be configured by providers at any parent level and are therefore much more flexible with less coupling than inputs. Routed components don't support values being passed through inputs anyway.

Comment: If you're able to use Angular v7.2 it allows for passing state now in the router using the `NavigationExtras` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879389/1148107

Comment: sadly, this doesnt work anymore (checked on angular 10) - you can pass data in route config, but not get it in cmp like in Gunther's answer above.
But you can use this:
this.router.events.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        const passedData = data.state.root.firstChild.data.passedData;
      }
    });

Answer (score 83):

I think since we don't have **$rootScope** kind of thing in angular 2 as in angular 1.x. We can use angular 2 shared service/class while in **ngOnDestroy** pass data to service and after routing take the data from the service in **ngOnInit** function:

**Here I am using DataService to share hero object:**

```
import { Hero } from './hero';
export class DataService {
  public hero: Hero;
}
```

**Pass object from first page component:**

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dataService.hero = this.hero; 
 }
```

**Take object from second page component:**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.hero = this.dataService.hero; 
 }
```

Here is an example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NpLKAgY3FkzhOK9eBeIb?p=preview)

Comment: This is beautiful, but how common in the Ng2 community is this? I can't recall reading it in the docs...

Comment: Comparing to other option like url parameters or other browser storage this seems to me better. I also did not see in any documentation to work like this.

Comment: Does it work when the user opens a new tab and copy paste the second component route? Can I able to fetch `this.hero = this.dataService.hero`? Will I get the values?

Comment: This is indeed very simple and every Angular developer knows but problem is once you refresh you loose data in the services. User will have to do all stuffs again.

Comment: @SantoshKadam the question is "How do I pass data to Angular routed components?" so passing data by ngOnDestroy and ngOnInit functions is a way, and always simple is the best. If user needs to get data after reload then there need to save data in a permanent storage and read again from that storage.

Comment: Warning! If you use this method and make refresh of the page, the data from the service will be deleted! Its better to store the values in a database

Comment: Where did you got the attribute dataService?

Answer (score 83):

Angular 7.2.0 introduced new way of passing the data when navigating between routed components:

```js
@Component({
  template: `<a (click)="navigateWithState()">Go</a>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(public router: Router) {}
  navigateWithState() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/123', { state: { hello: 'world' } });
  }
}
```

Or:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <a routerLink="/details" [state]="{ hello: 'world' }">Go</a>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

To read the state, you can access `window.history.state` property after the navigation has finished:

```js
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
  state$: Observable<object>;

  constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.state$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap
      .pipe(map(() => window.history.state))
  }
}
```

Comment: does not work for me, `window.history.state` returns something like `{navigationId: 2}` instead of returning the object I passed-in.

Comment: @Louis which Angular version are you using?

Comment: I am using angular version 8.1.0

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as Louis, with a lower version than his but still high enough that it's supposed to have that feature.

Comment: as part of the returned object, `navigationId` with a value is added. If no data is added, only the `navigationId` will be shown. Be see the passed data, go back or refresh your app and re-trigger the action that adds the data to the route and navigates to the next route (eg. button click). This will then add your data to the object.

Comment: After refreshing, the data gets cleared. You should store the data somewhere temporarily  if you want it to be available after refresh.

Comment: use { state: {data: {hello: 'world'}} } instead { state: { hello: 'world' } } to avoid navigationId ... restore it by history.state.data

Comment: There is a 640k data size browser limit on the state object.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425885/failed-to-execute-pushstate-on-history-error-when-using-window-history-pushs

Comment: @Louis I played around with the setting of state and it looks like "navigationId" is a reserved key that cannot be set using ```navigateByUrl()```. If you change the name of the key that you set in the "state" node to something like "navigation_id", you will then get ```window.history.state``` to return ```{navigation_id: <real navigation Id from object>, navigationId: 2}```.

Comment: try following this article. it works good for me. it uses ```history.state``` instead. https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255#:~:text=There%20are%20several%20ways%20how,and%20directly%20calling%20component's%20API

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['/123'], { state: { hello: 'world' } });` should work

Answer (score 48):

```
<div class="button" click="routeWithData()">Pass data and route</div>
```

well the easiest way to do it in angular 6 or other versions I hope is to simply to define your path with the amount of data you want to pass

```
{path: 'detailView/:id', component: DetailedViewComponent}
```

as you can see from my routes definition, I have added the `/:id` to stand to the data I want to pass to the component via router navigation. Therefore your code will look like

```
<a class="btn btn-white-view" [routerLink]="[ '/detailView',list.id]">view</a>
```

in order to read the `id` on the component, just import `ActivatedRoute`  like

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
```

and on the `ngOnInit` is where you retrieve the data

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        });
        console.log(this.id);
      }
```

you can read more in this article
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular-passing-parameters-to-route/

Comment: what if i want to send a complex object?
i don't want to bloat my routes to unmaintainable nonsense :(

Comment: @cmxl Use a shared service then.

Comment: @cmxl the idea with sending only the id or a simple string as data is to make the URL more 'sharable' and easily crawlable by bots etc. So that the resultant link can be shared by users of your app. For sending bigger objects, a service will be more effective.

Answer (score 38):

I looked at every solution (and tried a few) from this page but I was not convinced that we have to kind of implement a hack-ish way to achieve the data transfer between route.

Another problem with simple `history.state` is that if you are passing an instance of a particular class in the `state` object, it will not be the instance while receiving it. But it will be a plain simple JavaScript object.

So in my **Angular v10** (Ionic v5) application, I did this-

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/authenticate/username', {
    state: {user: new User(), foo: 'bar'}
});
```

[image]

And in the navigating component (`'/authenticate/username'`), in `ngOnInit()` method, I printed the data with `this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state`-

```js
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('>>authenticate-username:41:',
        this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state);
}
```

[image]

And I got the desired data which was passed-

[image]

Comment: `extras` ? is that something you just defined or an angular property?

Comment: That's a property from Angular.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for thanks mate..here is the upvote for you ;) I am also using it in ionic5 proj

Comment: @minigeek Yes, I'm also using it in Ionic. That's where I dug into Angular.

Comment: Just a doubt.  I am able to pass data.. but if I have to pass instance of inappbrowser to different module..its not able to serialise and threw error? Any idea other way?I don't really want to import whole module in my page just for one inappbrowser

Comment: In that case, the only way is to use the service reference. Basically, define a global service and use its scope to pass the reference. Or else you can use observables/subject as well.

Comment: Wonderful answer! It's important to remember that accessing the ```state``` (after routing to the new page) only worked on the ```constructor``` for me, and not inside the ```ngOnInit```. That's because the ```getCurrentNavigation()``` was null.

Comment: That's working fine for us. What's your Angular version @Itay?

Comment: @Itay I agree. I am using Angular 11. Current navigation scope is ended before ngOnInit(). So I had to take the state value from constructor.

Comment: Data is lost if page is refreshed

Comment: Yes, of course. That is supposed to get lost. You need to implement the caching on your own if it is a requirement.

Comment: it worked for me ONLY after i moved the code from ngOnInit to constructor

Comment: @OjonugwaJudeOchalifu data is lost because it is not stored into the URL (queryParams). Please vote up [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/47307) for the angular team to support storing JSON objects in urls

Answer (score 25):

It is 2019 and many of the answers here would work, depending on what you want to do. If you want to pass in some internal state not visible in URL (params, query) you can use `state` since 7.2 (as I have [learned](https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb) just today :) ).

From the blog (credits Tomasz Kula) - you navigate to route....

...from ts: `this.router.navigateByUrl('/details', { state: { hello: 'world' } });`

...from HTML template: `<a routerLink="/details" [state]="{ hello: 'world' }">Go</a>`

And to pick it up in the target component:

```
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.state$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap
      .pipe(map(() => window.history.state))
  }
```

Late, but hope this helps someone with recent Angular.

Comment: Isn't `state` lost when user refreshes? It would be fun to be able to persist it natively.

Comment: This is literally the only way that worked for me. Thanks 

Answer (score 21):

I this the other approach not good for this issue.
I thing the best approach is **Query-Parameter** by `Router` angular that have 2 way:

> Passing query parameter directly

With this code you can navigate to `url` by `params` in your html code:

```
<a [routerLink]="['customer-service']" [queryParams]="{ serviceId: 99 }"></a>
```

> Passing query parameter by `Router`

You have to inject the router within your `constructor` like:

```
constructor(private router:Router){

}
```

Now use of that like:

```
goToPage(pageNum) {
    this.router.navigate(['/product-list'], { queryParams: { serviceId: serviceId} });
}
```

Now if you want to read from `Router` in another `Component` you have to use of `ActivatedRoute` like:

```
constructor(private activateRouter:ActivatedRouter){

}
```

and `subscribe` that:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        // Defaults to 0 if no query param provided.
        this.page = +params['serviceId'] || 0;
      });
  }
```

Comment: this.router.navigate(['/product-list'], { queryParams: { serviceId: serviceId} }); can be replaced with this.router.navigate(['/product-list'], { queryParams: { serviceId} });

Answer (score 21):

Some super smart person (tmburnell) that is not me suggests re-writing the route data:

```
let route = this.router.config.find(r => r.path === '/path');
route.data = { entity: 'entity' };
this.router.navigateByUrl('/path');
```

As seen [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25658) in the comments.

I hope someone will find this useful

Comment: just found out about this and i feel like i need some stackoverflow points :)

Answer (score 17):

Solution with ActiveRoute (if you want pass object by route - use JSON.stringfy/JSON.parse):

Prepare object before sending:

```
export class AdminUserListComponent {

  users : User[];

  constructor( private router : Router) { }

  modifyUser(i) {

    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
          "user": JSON.stringify(this.users[i])
      }
    };

    this.router.navigate(["admin/user/edit"],  navigationExtras);
  }

}
```

Receive your object in destination component:

```
export class AdminUserEditComponent  {

  userWithRole: UserWithRole;      

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    super.ngOnInit();

      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.userWithRole.user = JSON.parse(params["user"]);
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: That works, but what if I do not want to expose all data in the URL?

Comment: You can encrypt data put it into params, after that encrypt in target component.

Comment: I've [created the service](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#Unrelated-Components-Sharing-Data-with-a-Service) for data sharing.

Comment: What is that `super.ngOnInit();` for?

Comment: Thank you. JSON.stringify() on the sending side and JSON.parse() on the receiving side worked for me.

Comment: was forced to do `JSON.stringify(user).toString()`  and then parse the result to `queryParams: {  'user':   [result here]  }`

Comment: Best and working solution after trying a few other solutions here

Answer (score 11):

Routes:

```
{ path: 'foo-route', component: FooComponent, data: { myData: false } },
```

In component access the data object once:

`pipe(take(1))` unsubsrcibes immediately so there is no memory leak and no need to manually unsubscribe

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { ... }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data); // do something with the data
  });
}
```

- remember to import needed stuff

Edit: the new `firstValueFrom()` could be better

Answer (score 5):

3rd approach is most common way to share data between components. you may inject the item service which you want to use in related component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Predicate } from '../interfaces'

import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {

    constructor() { }


    removeItemFromArray<T>(array: Array<T>, item: any) {
        _.remove(array, function (current) {
            //console.log(current);
            return JSON.stringify(current) === JSON.stringify(item);
        });
    }

    removeItems<T>(array: Array<T>, predicate: Predicate<T>) {
        _.remove(array, predicate);
    }

    setItem<T>(array: Array<T>, predicate: Predicate<T>, item: T) {
        var _oldItem = _.find(array, predicate);
        if(_oldItem){
            var index = _.indexOf(array, _oldItem);
            array.splice(index, 1, item);
        } else {
            array.push(item);
        }
    }


    addItemToStart<T>(array: Array<T>, item: any) {
        array.splice(0, 0, item);
    }


    getPropertyValues<T, R>(array: Array<T>, property : string) : R
    {
        var result = _.map(array, property);
        return <R><any>result;
    }

    getSerialized<T>(arg: any): T {
        return <T>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arg));
    }
}



export interface Predicate<T> {
    (item: T): boolean
}
```

Comment: The service gets instantiated when switching routes. So you loose data

Comment: @JimmyKane  You speaking about specifically when the page refreshes but if it doesn't refresh then the memory is still saved in a service. This should be the default behaviour since it will save loading many times.

Comment: @AaronRabinowitz right. Sorry for the confusion.  And sorry for the down vote. Wish I could undo it now. Too late. Was new to angular 2 and my problem with trying your approach was that I had the service provided to many components and not provided via the app module.

Answer (score 3):

Pass using JSON

```
  <a routerLink = "/link"
   [queryParams] = "{parameterName: objectToPass| json }">
         sample Link                   
  </a>
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you could show how the parameter is consumed in the receiving component as well - the whole route that it takes. Meaning if someone does not know how to pass a parameter, he is also not going to know how to use this parameter in the receiving component.  :)

Comment: A disadvantage to this is there's a size limitation to the querystring and sometimes you don't want object properties visible in the address bar.

Answer (score 3):

use a shared service to store data with a custom index. then send that custom index with queryParam. **this approach is more flexible**.

```
// component-a : typeScript :
constructor( private DataCollector: DataCollectorService ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.DataCollector['someDataIndex'] = data;
}

// component-a : html :
<a routerLink="/target-page" 
   [queryParams]="{index: 'someDataIndex'}"></a>
```

.

```
// component-b : typeScript :
public data;

constructor( private DataCollector: DataCollectorService ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
        (queryParams: Params) => {
            this.data = this.DataCollector[queryParams['index']];
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

say you have

1. component1.ts
2. component1.html

and you want to pass data to **component2.ts**.

- in component1.ts is a variable with data say

  ```
    //component1.ts
    item={name:"Nelson", bankAccount:"1 million dollars"}

    //component1.html
     //the line routerLink="/meter-readings/{{item.meterReadingId}}" has nothing to 
    //do with this , replace that with the url you are navigating to
    <a
      mat-button
      [queryParams]="{ params: item | json}"
      routerLink="/meter-readings/{{item.meterReadingId}}"
      routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
      View
    </a>

    //component2.ts
    import { ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

    /*class name etc and class boiler plate */
    data:any //will hold our final object that we passed 
    constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) {}

   ngOnInit() {

   this.route.queryParams
    .filter(params => params.reading)
    .subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params); // DATA WILL BE A JSON STRING- WE PARSE TO GET BACK OUR 
                         //OBJECT

    this.data = JSON.parse(params.item) ;

    console.log(this.data,'PASSED DATA'); //Gives {name:"Nelson", bankAccount:"1 
                                          //million dollars"}
     });
    }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use BehaviorSubject for sharing data between routed components.
A BehaviorSubject holds one value. When it is subscribed it emits the value immediately. A Subject doesn't hold a value.

In the service.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerReportService extends BaseService {
  reportFilter = new BehaviorSubject<ReportFilterVM>(null);
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { super(); }

  getCustomerBalanceDetails(reportFilter: ReportFilterVM): Observable<Array<CustomerBalanceDetailVM>> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Array<CustomerBalanceDetailVM>>(this.apiBaseURL + 'CustomerReport/CustomerBalanceDetail', reportFilter);
  }
}
```

In the component you can subscribe to this BehaviorSubject.

```
this.reportService.reportFilter.subscribe(f => {
      if (f) {
        this.reportFilter = f;
      }
    });
```

Note: Subject won't work here, Need to use Behavior Subject only.

Answer (score 2):

By default i won't use a guard for this one for me it is more can i enter the route or can i leave it. It is not to share data betweenn them.

If you want to load data before we entered a route just add an resolver to this one this is also part of the Router.

As very basic example:

Resolver

```
import { Resolve, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { take } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<User> {

    constructor(
        private userService: UserService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    resolve(): Observable<firebase.User> {
        return this.route.params.pipe(
            switchMap((params) => this.userService.fetchUser(params.user_id)),
            take(1)
        );
    }
}
```

put to the router:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
{
    path: "user/:user_id",
    component: MyUserDetailPage,
    resolve: {
        user: UserResolver
    }
  }
}]
```

get the data in our component

```
ngOnInit() {
    const user: firebase.User = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.user;
}
```

The downside on this approach is, he will enter the route first if he get the user data not before, this ensures the data for the user has been loaded and is ready on start of the component, but you will stay on the old page as long the data has been loaded (Loading Animation)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a parameter to the URL while navigating and simultaneously hide the data being passed to another component in the URL, you've to use both state and queryParams.

For Example:
Here clicking the edit button will route to CreateEmployeeComponent with the employee data.

**ViewEmployeeComponent:**

```
editEmployee(employee) {
  this.router.navigate(['employee/create'], { queryParams: { action: 'edit' }, state: { user: this.employee } }); }
```

Then the URL after routing to the component will be like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/employee/create?action=edit
```

**CreateEmployeeComponent**

```
    let employeeData = history.state.user;
    console.log(employeeData);
```

Comment: This was very easy to implement and makes my url clean
Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

One fine solution is to implement a Guard with canActivate method. In this scenario you can fetch data from a given api and let user access the component describe in the routing file. In the meantime one can set the data property of the route object and retrieve it in the component.

Let say you have this routing conf:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "/:projectName", component: ProjectComponent, canActivate: [ProjectGuard] }
]`
```

in your guard file you may have:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot)
: Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
return this.myProjectService.getProject(projectNameFoundElsewhere).pipe(
  map((project) => {
    if (project) {
      next.data = project;
    }
    return !!project;
  }),
);
```

}`

Then in your component

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.data.subscribe((value) => (this.project = value));
}
```

This way is a bit different than passing via a service since service keep the value in a behaviorSubject as long as it is not unset. Passing via tha guard make the data available for the current route. I havent check if the children routes keep the data or not.

Answer (score 0):

In scenario where data needs to be passed to another Route, best and simplest solution is using { window.localStorage }. Also, do not remember to remove data from local storage once its use is over.
I used ngOnDestroy's destroy() method to clean up this data.
This also resolves a problem where data is lost by page refresh.

Comment: From Review: Could you please provide some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to pass data to the routed components.

One of the approach is through the 'Query Paramaeters'.

If i want to pass data of table-id from the TableReservationComponent then i
can send it through query params.

```
TableReservationComponent.ts

TableId : number = 2;

this.router.navigate(['order'],{queryParams:{table_id : TableId}});
```

Now in the OrderComponent , we are able to get the table_id from the TableReservationComponent.

```
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit

{
    tableId : number ;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
       this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
       this.tableId = params['table_id'];
       
        });
    }

}
```

Here the table_id is coming from the TableReservationComponent in a Key Value Pair , and I can access in Order Component With the Key(params['table_id'])
and I can Use the table_id in the OrderComponent

Answer (score 0):

Angular 17.1 introduced new Router [info](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationBehaviorOptions#info) parameter to `NavigationExtras`:

.html:

```
<button routerLink="home" [info]="{ hello: 'world' }">
    Home
</button>
```

.ts:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('home', { info: { hello: 'world' } });
```

It's similar to state option, but it has two main differences. It's not saved in navigation history (`history.state`). And object is not copied or cloned, but assigned directly to the Router's current `Navigation`.