# Angular 2: Show user name instead of id on the url

Tags: angular, url

I'm with a MEAN stack project. It's near to finish, all works, but just I would like to know if it's possible to improve the url appearance.

For example, Now I'm finding the user by the _id, and the url is showing that _id. It's possible to continue finding by id but on the front url desplaying the user name?

Comment: Well if you know the user before navigating, you can store that user to a service and fetch it after navigating. It's hard to help further not knowing exactly what is going on in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search by `id`, you need that `id` in your url. But you could have both `id` and `userName` in url (searching by `id`, ignoring `userName`), maybe that would be solution for you:

`/user/:id/:userName` or `/user/:userName/:id`

If you don't like mongo ids (they are pretty long), you could transform them e.g. via [hashids](https://www.npmjs.com/package/short-mongo-id) or [short-mongo-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashids) module.

Or you could also add new indexed field to your users mongo table, that will have unique `userName` identifier, and use that instead of `id` field (but you will need to handle collisions in your backend).

Comment: Thank you @Martin Adámek, I'm finding well by _id, my question was if it's possible to overwrite that _id and replace it by the user name without modifying the query. So I want to continue finding by _id but showing the user name on the url. ¿is that possible through a helper service or whatever?

Comment: no its not, that what first sentence of my answer says... if you want to search by `id`, then you need to know that `id`... your frontend (angular app) have no clue about mapping of user name to id...

Comment: Thank you Martin for your time!, I will try what you said about ignoring. I thought that was possible. Just fyi (if others read the post) My question is similar than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533757/angular2-use-object-name-in-route-but-send-id-in-http