# Pass custom type as parameter in routing -> returns:[object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript, object, parameters, angular-router

I need to pass a variable of custom type (to a non child/parent component) when i click a link.

**Custom type**

```
export class Dati {
  fileJson;
  ricette: string[][];
  n_Ricette: 0;
  nPostazioni: number;
  postazioniNome: string[];
  defPostazione = "FRIGGITRICI";
}
```

and its initialization in **app.component.ts**:

```
dati : Dati = {
    fileJson: "",
    ricette: [[],[]],
    n_Ricette: 0,
    nPostazioni: 0,
    postazioniNome: [],
    defPostazione: "FRIGGITRICI",
  }
```

---

**app-routing.module**

```
....
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'option.component/:dati', component: OptionComponent },
]
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
....
```

**html link with routing** (app.component.html)

```
  <a routerLink="/option.component/{{dati}}" >Opzioni</a>
```

**option.component.ts** (destination of routing)

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(<Dati>(params["dati"]))
      });
  }
```

The result in the `console.log()` is: **`[object Object]`**.

How can I obtain my data?

**ps.** the links works fine and the data that are send are corect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing objects in routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994918/passing-objects-in-routing)

Comment: I've already see that, but it doesn't help me. thanks anyway

Comment: Well you may not feel it helps you, but it is the correct way of doing it, by using a service.

Comment: can you please show me? I'm stuck from hours