# Angular Routing for Children pages?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm making a signup page that has its own components for each page.

I had seen in a tutorial that you can use: `...SignUpRoutes` between the paths in the app-routing.module

For example, currently I have within sign-up-routing.module;

```
export const SignUpRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'sign-up',
      component: SignUpComponent,
      children: [
    { path: 'me',  component: MeComponent },
    { path: 'contact',  component: ContactComponent },
    { path: 'payment',  component: PaymentComponent }
      ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(SignUpRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class SignUpRoutingModule {}
```

Then in app-routing-module:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent  
  },
  {
    path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent 
  },
  ...SignUpRoutes,
  {
    path: 'login', component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**', redirectTo: ''
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I tried following the [Angular Routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#import-crisis-center-module-into-the-appmodule-routes) guide, however all pages are coming up as blank.
if I manually navigate to `/sign-up/contact` the routing wildcard in app-routing.module redirects to home but as blank. If I try to navigate to `/sign-up/me` then the page sort of loads, but is blank, and forms are on page but not visible.

Within the sign-up.component html template, there is a `<router-outlet>`.

Am unsure how to proceed as it feels like i've hit a brick wall...
Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: If you could build a little demo of your issue using stackblitz, it could help us better help you.

Comment: Hi Deborah, Here's the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sign-up-page-angular-with-children) that i've made roughly from my code. I'm trying to get the subpages to be handled by the sign-up's router but everything comes up blank.

Comment: I got it far enough to get something to display. But at this point I don't know enough about what you are trying to do to go much further. Here is an updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/sign-up-page-angular-with-children-chj5zx The next issue is that the signup component routes to the signup component. I think that *may* be a copy/paste issue with your original home component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@Deborahk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647604/deborahk) for the help!
Comparing your [github](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing/tree/master/APM-Final) repo with the sub pages helped understand how routing works, by loading a module as a child.

The **2** major issues as to why it *wasn't* working were:

- Authguards were being imported and breaking page
- Routing in App-Routing-Module was loading sign-up page, and then tried to place child page on top breaking the page. The fix loaded the sign-up page as a child to the route `sign-up`, so that the children were directed through to sign-up route.

For reference,
the changes to enable routing were:

The signup.module file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { SignupComponent } from './signup.component';
import { Step1Component } from './step1/step1.component';
import { Step2Component } from './step2/step2.component';
import { Step3Component } from './step3/step3.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: SignupComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'step1',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'step1',
            component: Step1Component
          },
          {
            path: 'step2',
            component: Step2Component
          },
          {
            path: 'step3',
            component: Step3Component
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    SignupComponent,
    Step1Component,
    Step2Component,
    Step3Component
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class SignupModule { }
```

And the App-routing file:

```
const routes: Routes = [


  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },

  { path: 'sign-up', children: [
      { path: '',  data: { preload: true },
      loadChildren: 'app/user/sign-up/signup.module#SignupModule' },
    ]},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

And in the signup component HTML,

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

was used to correctly navigate to the desired child page.

Thanks all for your input and guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something call Lazy Loading.

This is working like that :

In your AppRoutingModule :

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent,
    loadChildren: './signup/signup.module#SignupModule
  },
  {
    path: 'login', component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**', redirectTo: ''
  }
];
```

You need a new module (in my example the name is signup).
In this module (or in the rooting module file associate with) you will need to have those routes :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SignUpComponent
  },
  { 
    path: 'me',
    component: MeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent
  },
  { 
    path: 'payment',
    component: PaymentComponent
  }   
];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Looks like turning it into a Lazy loading feature had a bit more damage, error is coming up as [object] and sign-up won't load at all. I'm investigating it a bit further, as it's very strange..

Answer (score 0):

I got your stackblitz far enough to get something to display. But at this point I don't know enough about what you are trying to do to go much further. Here is an updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/sign-up-page-angular-with-children-chj5zx

The next issue is that the signup component routes to the signup component. I think that *may* be a copy/paste issue with your original home component?

Comment: Hi Deborah! Thanks for responding and having a look.. I'm reading into it further, and made a few changes to the stackblitz so the sign-up page would theoretically contain the smaller pages. However, when a route is initiated such as `/me`, it won't direct to `/sign-up/me` I'm going through stackoverflow to find other ways: Currently this is what I'm actually looking to do: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800217/trying-to-think-about-how-to-build-a-multi-step-form-in-angular-2). I think it would still be useful to understand how children routing would work in this situation..

Comment: I have an example that uses routing to define a set of tabs, but you could easily not display the tabs and have it be a multi-step set of pages. You can find it here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing/tree/master/APM-Final

Comment: That is very useful, and has helped to get the page-in-page router working. I'll edit your answer and add the code for reference. I'm just having trouble linking the pages together from the subcomponents..

Comment: Sorry the edit was rejected, so I added an answer for reference!