# Angular2 Cannot find a differ supporting object of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: json, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to get data from another view, like this:

```
    this.paramsSub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => this.categories = params['obj']);
this.paramsSub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => this.userInfo = params['usr']);
```

The data is sended in this way:

```
this.router.navigate(['/path/obj', {obj: this.categories, usr: this.userInfo}]);
```

I'm trying to show categories with a *ngFor in html like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <input type="checkbox" value={{category.id}}/> {{category.name}} 
    </div>
```

My error:

```
 Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I go to another view good, but IDK why my error, if I try to: JSON.parse the error change to

```
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

I have been reading about that error and it's look like I don't need the parse, so I'm very confusing.

Help, and thank you!

UPDATE

Here is the data before go to another view.

[image]

Comment: your `categories` is not a array. it is a object.

Comment: Can you share your data that is being passed. Pl. put that in question not in comment

Comment: @Smit there it is

Comment: you can stringfy ur object first and send over to the params. and then once u receive it... parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.router.navigate(['/path/obj', {obj: JSON.stringfy(this.categories), usr: JSON.stringfy(this.userInfo)}]);
```

This means now you can the object without any worry! :)

```
this.paramsSub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => this.categories = JSON.parse(params['obj']));
this.paramsSub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => this.userInfo = JSON.parse(params['usr']));
```

You may choose to do parsing, it is not necessary as, it is already in JSON format. It will parse for you.[automatically] :)

For more analysis and reading: [Angular 2: Passing Data to Routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157838/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes)