# How to add custom data to a route?

Tags: angular

I want to add some custom data to route when I define the routes.

How can I do that?

like:

```js
{
  path: 'department',
  component: DepartmentComponent,

  customdata: {
    name: 'foo',
    age: '23'
  }
}
```

I don't want the custom data to display in URL. I just use it internally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Passing Data to Routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157838/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the custom data to the route like this:

```js
[
   {path: 'inbox', data: {name: 'foo', age: 23}},
]
```

and read like this:

```js
class ConversationCmp {
    constructor(r: ActivateRoute) {
         r.data.subscribe((p) => {
              console.log(p);
         });
    }
}
```

It's defined on the `Route` interface:

```js
export interface Route {
  path?: string;
  ...
  data?: Data;
}
```

Comment: the `params` is an route property of `angular`, or is customized? Can I replace it with any property name I want?

Comment: yes, it's the property of the route. you can specify any object there the way I showed.

Comment: It seems it's not `Route` interface property.

Comment: @DuLin, yeah, sorry, it's `data` property. I've updated the answer

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: @torazaburo, not sure if there's any documention, but [this book](https://leanpub.com/router) shows that

Answer (score 2):

I do it in the following way:

```js
{ path: 'admin', canActivate: [RoleGuard], data: { roles: ['admin'] } }
```

I use it to add roles custom property to the route to be able to enable access only to users with a particular role, that I'm setting in Routes.