# Pass data from my class to a route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, slider, swiper.js

I'm trying to create an application with angular 2. I want to send the data to route from my class.

**Code**

```
@RouteConfig([
           {
             name: 'Slider', 
             component: thumbnail_gallery , 
             path: '/slider/:id' ,
             data : model 
           }
])
export class Watch extends Ext implements OnDestroy{
      public model: any; <=== i want pass this from route
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-in-angular-2-components-while-using-routing

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:-

```
@RouteConfig([

    {name: 'Slider', component: thumbnail_gallery ,path: '/slider/:id' , data : model }
])


export class Watch extends Ext implements OnDestroy{

    public model: any; 
    constructor(private router: Router){}

    Demorouting(){
       this.router.navigate(['/slider', {id: this.modal}])
    }

}
```