# Angular2 router: Why don't we have states anymore on routes

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my `app.routes`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: "login",
      component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
      path: "users",
      component: UsersComponent
    },
    {
      path: "error",
      component: ErreurComponent
    },
    {
      path: "more/complex/path",
      component: FooComponent
    },
    {
      path: "",
      component: HomepageComponent,
    }
]

export const APP_ROUTER_MODULE = RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

Why can't I specify a state or a name for my routes ? If I want to know if wether or not I am on the error page, I then have to check the current route and look for what I have specified in "path" (see also my `FooComponent` above). I found this a bit silly. Is there anyway to work around this ?

Comment: You can pass `data`.

Comment: Jeez, my bad you right, I was looking at the wrong data. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: "login",
      component: LoginComponent,
      data: { name: 'r1'}
    },
    {
      path: "users",
      component: UsersComponent,
      data: { name: 'r2'}
    },
    {
      path: "error",
      component: ErreurComponent,
      data: { name: 'r3'}
    },
    {
      path: "more/complex/path",
      component: FooComponent,
      data: { name: 'r4'}
    },
    {
      path: "",
      component: HomepageComponent,
      data: { name: 'r5'}
    }
]
```

```
class SomeComponent {
  constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
    route.data.forEach(data => console.log(data['name']));
  }
}
```

See also [How do I pass data in Angular 2 components while using Routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-in-angular-2-components-while-using-routing/36835156#36835156)

Comment: Could that bit 
  constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
    route.data.forEach(data => console.log(data['name']));
  }
be used in an external service ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "external service", but you can use a guard for example https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Comment: What I meant was: Is it possible to have something common to all my module's components where I can get this data['name'] information.

Comment: What I want may actually be the resolve guard. Thanks !