# How to get the previous state name in the current state in Angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am working on implementing ecommerce website in Angular4.Here I have a checkout page where I have to display individual as well as cart products based on the user coming from the previous state.My problem is that I need to get the state name from which user has navigated to the current page,for this purpose I am  checking a condition. I am stuck at getting the state name in Angular4 . How can I get the previous state name in Angular4?

Comment: In angular app state is maintained by routing. You can define a specific routing for each state. However, we need more detail about your specific problem.

Comment: I just want to get the previous state name after navigation

Comment: Just put in as a value in your route check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-in-angular-2-components-while-using-routing

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service.

One of the uses of services is to store data. This data persists across component changes and routing and others.

Just generate a service (maybe using angular-cli: `ng g service your-service-name`. Add a variable to that service and call it, for example, "state".

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class YourService
{
  state: String = '';

  constructor()
  {

  }
}
```

then, in your component files, you just import it in your components

```
import { YourService } from '../../path/to/your.service';
```

and in the constructor:

```
constructor(                
    private yourService:YourService          
)
{}
```

and anywhere in the code you can do

```
this.yourService.state = "something";
```

and do your checks and so on

Comment: In "something",What can I place?

Comment: just make an enumeration of your states. Say "visitor", "loggedIn", "checkout", "transactionSuccess", "transactionFailure",  ...any strings. You can add more variables other than state.