# Can Angular 4 pass an object along the route?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component and a child component. I was trying to navigate to child component using `route.navigate` based on `button click`. Is it possible to pass an object with `route.navigate` to the child component?

Comment: it is not possible to pass an object through router. you need to create a service and set the value in that and get it from another component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data to Angular routed components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I navigate from a material table to a form and pass a raw id (it is possible to pass all the raw object)

Here's my code :

```
<mat-cell id="idVtitle" *cdkCellDef="let row">
  <button id="idValidationScreenButton" mat-button [routerLink]="['/validation', row.documentid]">{{row.title}}
  </button>
</mat-cell>
```

And in my ValidationComponent refering to the rout validation I have something like this:

```
  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _router: Router,) {
  }
```

And then calling this this._route.params.map((params: any) => params.id) to get the param (in my case I use the param to call the backend)

```
private fetchDocument() {
    this._route.params
      .map((params: any) => params.id)
      .flatMap((id: string) => this._sharedService.fetchOneDocument(id))
      .subscribe((doc: any) => this.docToValidate = doc);
  }
```

I hope this could help.

Comment: Thanks. Able to pass id.

Comment: Hi, do you know if it is possible to pass data without having it appear on the url as query parameters?