# Redirecting to another page in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I want to **redirect to another page by clicking on the link**. For that I tried out below code:

`home.component.html`

```
<a [routerLink]="['/datalineage']">
Click Here
</a>
```

`app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { DatalineageComponent } from './datalineage/datalineage.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'datalineage', component: DatalineageComponent, data: { title: 'Test' } }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            appRoutes, { enableTracing: true }
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: []
})
```

`datalineage.component.ts`

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datalineage',
  templateUrl: './datalineage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datalineage.component.css']
})
export class DatalineageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

But it is not going to the clicked page, it shows `http://localhost:4200/datalineage` in URL but it remains on the same page.
What can be the issue?

Comment: please add your route configuration `appRoutes`

Comment: please, show your DatalineageComponent and app module also

Comment: @SplitterAlex where?

Comment: since you have enabled tracing, why not also post tracing logs?

Comment: @HiteshKansagara added, pls chk

Comment: @Pengyy how to do that? I am new here.

Comment: @PathikVejani check your developer tool's console log.

Comment: if you are already on `DatalineageComponent`, then you will not change anything. Also, you need to have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` somewhere in your html-code (maybe inside app.component.html)?

Comment: Is there any error in console ?

Comment: @John in whch file i have to add that?

Comment: @gauravbhavsar no.

Comment: @PathikVejani wherever you like, but usually it is inside `app.component.html`

Comment: @John i put that but now it shows both pages data after clicking on the link.

Comment: @PathikVejani that may be because you are also adding `<app-datalineage-component></app-datalineage-component>` inside the app.component.html file. You only need the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Then the component defined in your `appRoutes` will be visible for the given route.

Comment: @John In `app.component.html` I have home page data also. If i put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` then it shows both page data on clicking.

Comment: @John if i remove `<app-home></app-home>` then it will not display link where i want to click and redirect it.

Comment: Try `routerLink="/datalineage"`, also all that you need is here @ https://angular.io/guide/router#basics-wrap-up

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan same, not redirecting

Comment: @PathikVejani it is easier to help if you have a stackblitz or similar, but my guess is that you have to structure your code a bit differently in order for it to work. The router-outlet will replace the component based on the path. All other html defined in app.component.html will still be visible, even though the path changes.

Comment: @John what i have to change?

Comment: @PathikVejani "@John what i have to change? " -> Your attitude ;) The community tries to understand you and give support. Be respectful ;)

Comment: @meorfi what i did disrespectful?

Comment: have you added app-rounting module in app-module

Answer (score 0):

navigation template.
    
      `<h1>Working Routing</h1>
      <nav>
        <a [routerLink]=" ['./'] " routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
        <a [routerLink]=" ['./datalineage'] " routerLinkActive="active">Data Lineage</a>
      </nav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>`

app.routing template:

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DatalineageComponent } from './datalineage/datalineage.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'datalineage', component: DatalineageComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

app.module template:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true })
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: []
})
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/router

For how to pass data between components check these sources:

[How do I pass data to Angular routed components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components)

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: what should be in `app.component.html`?

Comment: it is not redirecting to `HomeComponent` if nothing is passed in url

Comment: you can add the first snippet of code, under **navigation template** for now. Later you maybe will want to extract navigation in a separate component ;)

Comment: why it is not loading `HomeComponent`?

Comment: "it is not redirecting to HomeComponent if nothing is passed in url " - it should, I set a `path: ''` which will handle the empty routes, otherwise... let me update the routing . 1 min

Comment: i got it but still it is not redirecting to home

Comment: would you liek to check appRoutes snippet ? :) I've updated it. May it solves

Comment: can you remove what you have in app.component.html and paste just the snippet from **navigation template** section, just to ensure it is working. There is not a big problem with routing if you'll follow the instructions from the **Reference** I mentioned.

Comment: i removed and it shows pasted data of urs. so it is working but when i click on "home" link it is not redirecting.