# Send data from child to parent within routing - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components: ProcessComponent & ClientTypeComponent binded to routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
            {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
            {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
            {
                path: 'process', component: ProcessComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
                    {path: 'client-type', component: ClientTypeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
                ]
            }

];
```

How can I just send a simple boolean value from /process/client-type to /process

I can't use neither data-binding or EventEmitter since I don't use nested components but nested routes.

There is probably a way but I can't find any answers.

Comment: something like this (from the angular docs):   `this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);` or as already mentioned, use a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i think it's duplicate of [How do I pass data to Angular routed components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components)

Comment: this isn't a duplicate but maybe I can use it. Send an event to a service that sends an other event to my parent component

Comment: yes you can use it and i think it proper way to pass a data from one to other

Answer (score 0):

You should use service to get the value. You store the value in service before routing to `'client-type'`. Get the value in ngOninit of `ClientTypeComponent`

Comment: The value can change in ClientType component, so it can't be onInit