# Angular Passing Data Between Routes

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a little problem using routes in angular 4. You know, when I am trying to pass data from a component to another using `navigate('root', data)`, I just received `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`.

**Component**

```
export class FillRequestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: Router, private dataRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const key: Products = this.dataRoute.snapshot.params['objectProducts'];
    console.log(key);
  }
```

**Interface**

```
export interface Products {

  color: string,
  question: string,
  surname: string,
  icon: string,
  selected: boolean,
  transparent: boolean
}
```

**Send Method**

```
const data = {
      category: this.optionSelected,
      objectProducts: this.optionSelected === 'CREDIT' ? this.productCreditList :
        this.productAccountsList
    };

    this.route.navigate(['/requests/fill', data]);
```

Comment: I have found that passing an object via a route is not a friendly pattern, as a main point of having a route is so that a user can navigate directly there. If they navigate directly there, will the parent still be able to pass down the object? Usually not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you pass an object as a route parameter, it causes to call `toString` on that object and you get the result `[object Object]` from the object.

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(obj.toString());
```

If you want to pass complex type, you need to `stringify` it to a `string` and pass as a `string`. After when you get it, you need again to parse into an object.

```
this.route.navigate(['/requests/fill', JSON.stringify(data)]);
```

and access later

```
const key: Products = JSON.parse(this.dataRoute.snapshot.params['objectProducts']);
```

Comment: I think this is not an extensible way of doing things, having all this data in the URL , using to stringify and then parse... seem like not the proper way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 86):

In the current version this is now available in `@angular/router`.

[Angular 7.2](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state) introduces route state to `NavigationExtras`, which takes an object literal similar to `queryParams`, etc.

The state can be set imperatively:

```
this.router.navigate(['example'], { 
  state: { example: 'data' } 
});
```

or declaratively:

```
<a routerLink="/example" [state]="{ example: 'data' }">
  Hello World
</a>
```

And read in a **top-level component** using:

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
```

or within **child components** using:

```
window.history.state
```

Added a working example of it being used on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mm8jfa?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras)

`/example` should be sent as list right?

Comment: Link: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uapqsj) could you please check this is not working

Comment: @Chenna you're right it was supposed to be a list.  I thought initially you meant you couldn't have `/` at the start.  I'll have a look at your example

Comment: I got it, it has to be mentioned in `constructor`

Comment: Moving this line  to the constructor works!
this.name = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.example;

Comment: if you want to get this outside of constuctor (for example in ngOnInit) than use window.history.state

Comment: Does anyone know why `this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state` doesn't work in child components?

Comment: Is window.history.state working in child component? It is not working

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass list of data in params

So you need convert to string the list of objects then pass

```
navigate('root',   JSON.stringify(data))
```

Then do parsing while get this

```
const key: Products =JSON.parse(this.dataRoute.snapshot.params['objectProducts']);
```