# Configure Route Guard

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

I have a route guard that needs to be configured. On some route we want to check if our `user client` is ready, on some others we want to check if our `team client` is ready etc.

I've my route guard that looks like this

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientReadyGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
    constructor(
        private clientName: string,
        private router: Router ,        
        private apolloState: ApolloStateService,

    ) {
        debugger;
    }

    canActivate(...) {
       // do things with clientName
    }
```

and from this guard I'd like to have multiple guards: one that protects with `clientName` 'all-users', one with 'user', one with 'team', and so on.

To have :

```
canActivate: [
   AllUserClientReadyGuard,
   UserClientReadyGuard,
   TeamClientReadyGuard,

]
```

To do so I tried with injection token with no luck; (`NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken router token!`).

```
export const ROUTER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Router>('router token');
export const APOLLO_STATE_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ApolloStateService>('apollo state token');


export const UserClientReadyGuard = new InjectionToken<ClientReadyGuard>(
    'user client ready guard',
    {
        providedIn: 'root', factory: () => new ClientReadyGuard(
            USER_CLIENT,
            inject(ROUTER_TOKEN),
            inject(APOLLO_STATE_TOKEN),
        )
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using inheritance. Using [{ data }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components) from the router is arguably a better option in general though. But since I ended up needing different behaviors for the guards extending allows me to override methods. I guess it's case dependent.

```
export abstract class ClientReadyGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

    constructor(
        protected router: Router,
        protected apolloState: ApolloStateService,
        protected client: string
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
        return this.checkReady(this.client);
    }


    protected checkReady(client: string): Observable<boolean> {
        //...
    }    
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalDataClientReadyGuard extends ClientReadyGuard {
    constructor(
        protected router: Router,
        protected apolloState: ApolloStateService,
    ) {
        super(router, apolloState, GLOBAL_DATA_CLIENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think using `data` is good at all, and I'm irritated that this is gaining traction as "best practice" in the angular community. `data` has two pitfalls specifically. 1) Multiple guards may wish to use the same property on the `data` object for different reasons, causing a conflict. 2) You can get no help in the form of auto-suggest or static checking from languages like TypeScript with the `data`.