# How to pass data on click in angular 5 from parent component to child component?

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I want to pass data on button click of parent component to child component and render child component as a separate page in angular 5 instead of rendering child component in parent's template.

Suppose, My child component is 'AstronautComponent' and when I add ,

```
<app-astronaut *ngFor="let astronaut of astronauts"
  [astronaut]="astronaut">
</app-astronaut >
```

this in parent template it is showing child template on same page instead of separate page.Actually I am able to get data from parent to child but on same parent template.I am using @Input annotation with service(as Observable).

Kindly Help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by separate page? Is it a new tab in the browser altogether?

Comment: if you're opening a new page, I believe router params are your only option. but why use a single page application framework like angular and not use a single page is beyond me

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, it's a new tab.If parent is at 127.0.0.1:4200/parent then new tab at 127.0.0.1:4200/astronaut.

Comment: @Stavm As you suggested will go through router params.But do I achieve a parent template is fully replaced by child template using SPA?If yes then please tell how do it?

Comment: @NareshPawar - Did the solution help?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, I did it using router params.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `router` to open child component in new page like:

```
<a routerLink="/your_link">click here to open child component</a>
```

and define its path in

`app.module.ts` to open child component like:

```
{ path: 'your _link', component: child_component }
```

Answer (score 0):

render child component as a separate page?

Then there is no parent child relationship

Have a parent component with router outlet

**Parent.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

define routes for your 2 components with data

{ 
path: 'your _link', 
component: child_component,
data: {
... any data
}
}

while navigating from component1 to component2 pass the data

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36835156/2742156

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly setup Angular routing defining your routes separately for both `parent` and `astronaut`. Please note these do not have any parent / child relationship anymore.

Once you have the data, you may store it in localStorage and navigate / open new tab using

```
window.open('http://127.0.0.1:4200/astronaut', '_blank');
```

The above statement will render another Angular application in the second tab with the astronaut component rendered. At this point of time in `ngOnInit()`, you may check the `localStorage` for the desired data, and if one is present, you can simply access it and show it in HTML as desired. This way, you no longer need an `@Input()` property.