# How do i query/get data from mongoDB based on input field/text

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

Hellow there. thanks for clicking on this post. i would like to know how do i get/query data from mongodb based on the input field. example is if i were to input "USA" in the input field named" location" it will only get data that has USA in it and the data will be displayed on the next page.
How do i get this to work when i click on a button. 
i will link some screenshots of my webite and code(i have a feeling my code is completely wrong.)

[error im facing after pasting ur code and code for passing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frsbH.png)

[this is my home.component.html line40. it is to pass the data to next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05CsN.png)

[home page where i will be inserting a country in the  enter country field, once i click on "find" it will GET data from mongo based on the country ive insertted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQNrb.png)

[this is the page where the data will be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns5V0.png)

here is some codes ive tried to mess around with(havent tested if it works)

```js
 //this is in my api.js file
//get data from "listing"(which is my db collection) based on "inputcountry( the inputfield)"
router.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('listing').find({"inputCountry": req.body.inputCountry}).toArray( (err, results) => {
        console.log('got search')
        res.send(results)});
    });


//this is in my service .ts file (named getservice)
//this is for the searching of house based on location
  searchHouse() {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('./api/home');
    }
    
    //this is in my home. component.ts file (where the searching will happen)
     constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private getService: GetService) {
  // Retrieve posts from the API
    this.getService.searchHouse().subscribe(searchedhouses => {
    this.searchedhouses = searchedhouses;
  });
  }
```

```html
<!--this is in my home.component.html where there is the input field named "inputcountry" and submit button -->

 <form [formGroup] = "myForm" (ngSubmit) = "searchHouse (myForm)">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCountry">Enter Country</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="inputCountry" id="inputCountry"   name = "inputCountry" placeholder="Location e.g Singapore              .">
            </div>
            
              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" routerLink="/houses" type="submit" >Find</button>
     
            </form>
```

Comment: on change of that input field, call a api, with that iunput field value.
now in that api, find with `Regex` in mongo may be. and return the value to show it,

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty erm i dont really understand what u just said. do u mind writinng it as one of the answer?

Comment: confirm me if this is the one you want, will make as answer then:
in place of `{"inputCountry": req.body.inputCountry}` do:
`{"inputCountry": { $regex: req.body.inputCountry ,$options: 'i' }}` in the query section of `.find`.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty what does $option : 'i' do?. and do i have to install anything for regex to work?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty and is it possible to make it so that when i click the find button it will get the data ? and display it on the next page?

Comment: yeah, so, that "i" is for ignore case for regex, and it will work only when you call the api with the input box data, on click of the find button

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty ok. so can u make it as answer  based on my question. appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, have added the answer, let me know if worked.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty ok will get back to you

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty i have some updates for you . plz reply . read the comments in  answer u posted

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regexp in order to search data in mongodb as per your input field.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Answer (score 0):

well, so as per the code,

in the backend code, for the api, you can place a Regexified input, 
for the expected output,

```
router.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('listing').find({"inputCountry": { $regex: req.query.inputCountry ,$options: 'i' }}).toArray( (err, results) => {
        console.log('got search')
        res.send(results)});
    });
```

this above code will give you the results in the output. which you can show in next page may be in frontend.

in angular there is many better approach is available for short you can do something like this:

```
 onSubmit = function (allValues) {
    console.log(allValues);
    this.http.get("http://localhost/home?inputCountry="+allValues.inputCountry).subscribe((data) => {
   //you will get the result here, show that to user. 
});
  };


<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputCountry">Enter Country</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="inputCountry"
      id="inputCountry"
      name="inputCountry"
      placeholder="Location e.g Singapore              ."
    />
  </div>

  <button
    class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase"
    routerLink="/houses"
    type="submit"
  >
    Find
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: but how do i show them in another page.component.html instead of in the url?

Comment: can i use routing to pass the data i retrieved ? from one component to another. so as for my case pass data from home component to the next component?

Comment: i guess this can help you, with how to pass data to some other component:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: and btw what u do mean  by this --->>    //you will get the result here, show that to user.

Comment: that is just a comment, where you will get the data, and you can use that data to show , may be you can show it there only, or you can  send it t somewhere else as well.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification ill use the routing.ts to pass my data since i know how to.

Comment: IM  getting an erro bro. i inspect console on google chrome and this is what it shows . ill paste the error above

Comment: hey there is there any other way to communicate with you. its quite hard to show u recent updates  about errors and stuff.? maybe add me on facebook and we will go from there? 
James Franco Hadi on facebook.

Comment: i am not able to successfully pass the data to another page . pls help me sir