# How to pass server data when routing to component

Tags: angular

I am getting data in `abc.component.ts` and trying to `pass` this data to component which is routed.`

This data should not be pass alongwith routes, since it is a json object and it can be very big data and route url will expose data.

## .ts

```
data = {"key":1,"value":2}

this.router.navigate(['dashboard']); //<=== when routing pass 'data' into dashboard.component.ts

this.router.navigate(['page']); //<=== when routing pass 'data' into page.component.ts
```

## .html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

## dashboard.component.ts

```
alert(data) <============ requirement
```

Answer (score 0):

In your [routing component](https://angular.io/guide/router), simply add another [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) called data, populate it with whatever you might need, for example:

```
{
    path: "path:/id",
    component: MyComponent,
    data: {
        type: "static"
    }
},
```

Then, simply [subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components) for the data in the respective component, for example:

> **NOTE:** You need to add ActivatedRoute (as shown) in your constructor for this to work.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
        const type = data.type;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** [Here is another valuable resource.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components)

**EDIT 2:** [Another valuable resource here](https://angular.io/guide/router#navigating-back-to-the-list-component), which states that you can pass the data as a second parameter using the `.navigate()` method, e.g. - `this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);`

Comment: That will send data which is large data to travel with routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a second parameter to navigate function.

```
data = {"key":1,"value":2}
this.router.navigate(['dashboard'], data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const routes = [
     {
        // ...
        component: AppComponent,
        children: [
             {
                 // ...
                 component: ChildRouteComponent
             }
        ]
     }
];
```

You inject the `AppComponent` into the child component.

```js
@Component({...})
export class ChildRouteComponent {

    public constructor(app: AppComponent) {
        console.log(app.getData());
    }
}
```

The `AppComponent` has to provide the function `getData()` or a public property. Anything you want from the parent component to the child.

If the data is async, then have `getData()` return an observable of the data.

Comment: This is a specific answer. However, I am looking for generic solution when the two components having no relation and they may not be a part of a module.

Comment: @Mahi shared service then.