# How do i transfer data from one route to another route in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, aws-amplify

I'm setting up a user registration workflow based on angular and aws-amplify. After i signed the new user up a confirmation step is needed and i want to redirect the user to a confirmation component where he needs to enter a confirmation code.

Here is my signUp method to create a new user:

```
  signUp() {
    if (this.signUpForm.valid === true) {
      this.auth
        .signUp(this.signUpForm.get('email').value, this.signUpForm.get('password').value)
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
```

Instead of simply logging the data i want to route to the confirmation page. So the final result should be something like this:

```
  signUp() {
    if (this.signUpForm.valid === true) {
      this.auth
        .signUp(this.signUpForm.get('email').value, this.signUpForm.get('password').value)
        .then(data => this.router.navigate(['auth/confirm']))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
```

In order to process the registration confirmation i need access to some content of the `data` that represents the newly created user.

How can i make the `data` object accessible in my target component?

I found a solution like https://github.com/mlabieniec/AngularMaterialPWA/blob/master/partTwo/src/app/auth/confirm-code/confirm-code.component.ts

But i do not like the approach to use the angular-environment for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really nice article on a few different ways to pass data in different scenarios. The new method as mentioned by Chiffie is not included and this is a perfectly viable approach as well. https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/. The sharing data using a service is how i would tackle this personally.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36835156/10179262
hope this answer helps in sharing data to another component through route.