# Angular 7 - how to check if the user directly navigate into the page

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I have an app with the next routing structure:

```
{
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: "list",
            component: ListViewComponent
        },
        {
            path: "dashboard",
            component: DashboardComponent
        },
        {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'dashboard'
        },
        {
            path: "**",
            redirectTo: 'dashboard'
        }
    ]
}
```

how I can check if the user navigates into the page by full path eg `home/list` or by `redirectTo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the url by adding:

```
path: 'team/:id',
component: TeamComponent,
canActivate: ['canActivateTeam']
```

Here ['canActivateTeam'] can be a function in a service.

Comment: I think should be a more elegant approach to check this.

Comment: What type of approach is actually you are looking?

Comment: I don't want to create a separate service + guard to check this. Probably we can do it by `ActivatedRoute` or `Router`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state while navigating to the url and pass it a user defined value.

According to angular documentation:

> Developer-defined state that can be passed to any navigation. Access this value through the Navigation.extras object returned from router.getCurrentNavigation() while a navigation is executing.

For more info refer: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: is related to manual navigation, in my case I need to catch this by route config.

Comment: @TarasKovalenko You should be able to use data similarly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components might help you