# Angularjs - How to pass data between routes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have the following code:

```
app.factory(CService.Id,
    ["$rootScope", "$route", "$routeParams", "$location", "$timeout",
        ($rootScope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $timeout) =>
            new CService($rootScope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $timeout)]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'page1.html',
                controller: 'page1Controller',
                controllerAs: 'ctl',
                reloadOnSearch: false
            }).
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'page2.html',
                controller: 'page2Controller',
                controllerAs: 'ctl',
                reloadOnSearch: false
            }).
```

in page1.html

```
<div>
 <input ng-model="ctl.field">
</div>
```

Now I want to pass value `field` from page1.html to page2.html, when click on a redirect button (`this.location.path(/page2.html)`) for example, how do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: have you checked this question/answer ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components