# Angular - How to send Data from Child Component to Parent with Routing?

Tags: angular

I want to set a SampleData and send it to Parent Component in Angular.
It works fine when the Child Component purely inside of Parent Component.

However, I want to set different Child Components in a Parent Component by Routing.

so I put  in parent.component.html,
and the Child Component is called like this and does not work anymore...

```
{ path: "sample1", component: Sample1Component }
```

Can anyone see my code and give me a solution...?

Center Component would be a Parent Component, 
and Sample1 Component would be a Child Component.

You may download the code to see more detail from [Here](https://kbj0109.tistory.com/attachment/cfile6.uf@991789445DFBBB66027A04.zip)

**app.router.module.ts**

```
const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/", pathMatch: "full" }, 
  { path: "sample1", component: Sample1Component },
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "/", pathMatch: "full" } 
];
```

**center.component.html**

```
<div (sampleEvent)="SampleData = $event">
  Center Area Title from Sample 1 : {{ SampleData }}
</div>

<!--if sample 1 Component is called by this Router, 'Center Area Title value does not change -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<!-- if sample 1 Component is called by below, 'Center Area Title value changes-->
<!-- <app-sample1 (sampleEvent)="SampleData = $event"></app-sample1> -->
```

**sample1.component.html**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Center Area Title" #sampleTitle (keyup)="onChange(sampleTitle.value)"  />
```

**sample1.component.ts**

```
export class Sample1Component implements OnInit {
  @Output("sampleEvent") sampleEvent = new EventEmitter();

  onChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.sampleEvent.emit(value);
  }

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Please somebody help me out here....

Comment: This post may be helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route components do not have an inherent relationship to the component which contains the `RouterOutlet` (`<router-outlet>`). It is likely *possible* to find a way to emit data from the routed component through the `RouterOutlet`, but this is not the canonical way of solving this problem. A more conventional solution would be to use an external singleton (service) which houses observables used to transfer data between components which do not have a direct inheritance relationship.

1. Create an `@Injectable()` service class with an `Subject` field for the event
2. Add this service to the module providers
3. Inject this service into both the route component (`Sample1Component`) and the container component (`CenterComponent`)
4. Listen to changes to the observable field in the container component (`CenterComponent`)
5. Emit changes to the observable subject in the route component (`Sample1Component`)

Comment: Thanks for ur answers. Now, I used Service to implements what I want based on your comment. :))))