# Is it safe to pass data through the Router state in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I recently learned about passing data between router components like this:

```
this._router.navigate(['page2'], {state : {myObject : this.secretInfo }});
```

And reading the data like this:

```
window.history.state
```

Is it safe to pass sensitive data this way?

Is there any way that someone could read the data just by looking through the JS source?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe this is a safe practice at all. It looks like `window.history.state` is something that's natively built into the browser, not specific to Angular *(see the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/state) for this)* and you can access all of it's properties by just calling it in a `console.log`. Any user could easily pull up the inspector and see the data - and not only see it, but mutate that data as well!

Additionally, in any front-end application, you're never going to have "**secret data**" - even in Angular. Here's a good [Stack Exchange question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221277/how-good-are-angular-route-guards-from-a-security-standpoint) on why that is. If you have data that you want to keep secret, or lock down, you'll need to lock it down in the back-end on the server. For example, only showing a user's data, to that specific user, who is "*logged in*" on your server.

To add to this, that's not the only way to pass data in between routes in Angular components. If you're interested, here's a good S[O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components?rq=1) on that, and an article that was mentioned in the comments for different ways to do this: http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/12/3-simple-ways-to-share-data-through.html

Comment: Thanks man, you are right. This quote from StackExchange resumes it well "Server side guards are about data protection. Client-side guards are about providing a smoother user experience."