# Pass data using using data object Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass data using routing by passing data directly in the routing, see example to be more clear.
I try to do it this way to see all the possibilities to pass from the given.

In my example I want to pass the variable toto to another component

Thanks in advance.

**one component**

```
public toto:string = 'pass this data to two component'
```

**routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = {
 { 
   path: 'two',
   component: TwoComponent,
    data: toto // I have an error here that says cannot find 'toto
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data to Angular routed components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to put data in `{}` as data is a property of `Routes` type, instead do this:

```
{
   path: 'two',
   component: TwoComponent,
   data:  { //pass your data as object}
}
```

or even:

```
   {
       path: 'two',
       component: TwoComponent,
       data:  _variable //if you don't need to use object
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help, can I pass my variable toto in to retrieve it in another component?

Comment: Sure. In `ngOnInit` in `TwoComponent` use this code: `this.activatedroute.data.subscribe(data => {//access data})`

Comment: Also don't forget to `import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'`

Comment: when I try I get this error : ' Cannot find ' toto' why ? the error comes from my routing

Comment: `toto` is a local variable in `OneComponent` and it can't be access in `routing.module`. You don't need to path data in your module. Do it in your `TwoComponent` itself. Here is a link t guide you: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-data-to-route/