# How can I pass data from custom component(nb-select) to main component(ng2-smart-table)

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table, ngx-admin

I'm trying to get selected data from the component nb-select and pass it to ng2 smart table , after  implementing the code below the nb-select diplayed correctly in the cell of the table also I can see the the data selected but in nb-list Component not where I want I hope explained well my problem, sorry for my english , I'm stuck since one week   
**nb-list.html :**

```
<nb-select
  [(ngModel)]="selectedlist"
  multiple
  placeholder="Liste TPE disponible"
  (ngModelChange)="change($event)"
>
  <nb-option *ngFor="let tpe of listOfTpeNoneBinded" [value]="tpe.sn">
    {{ tpe.sn }}
  </nb-option>
</nb-select>
```

**nb-list.ts :**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Apollo } from "apollo-angular";
import { UserService } from "../user/user.service";

@Component({
  selector: "ngx-nb-list",
  templateUrl: "./nb-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./nb-list.component.scss"],
})
export class NbListComponent implements OnInit {
  listOfTpeNoneBinded;
  selectedlist;
  // @Input() value;
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo, private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getNoBinded();
  }
  change(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
    
  getNoBinded() {
    this.apollo
      .query<any>({ query: this.userService.getNoBinded() })
      .subscribe(({ data }) => {
        console.log("getNoBindedTPE", data);
        this.listOfTpeNoneBinded = data.getNoBindedTPE;
      });
  }
}
```

**my code in ng2 smart table**

```
bindedSn: {
        title: "bindedSn",
        type: "html",
        editor: {
          type: "custom",
          valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => {
            return row;
          },

          // data exists in nb list compoent i want to get the data from nb list component to here
          component: NbListComponent,
        },
      },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data to Angular routed components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components)

Comment: Usually when you don't have a parent-child relationship between your components or they don't share the same parent and you still want to be able to share data between them, you would use a service to do that.