# send parameter to component from angular routing module

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, url-routing

My application have a lot of modules and each module has its own routing class.

```
  {
    path: 'periodic-documents', data: {allowedRoles: ['11A06A', 'Admin']}, component: PeriodicDocumentsComponent
  },
```

above is the example of a module routing.

So I need a way to pass data to "PeriodicDocumentsComponent" component from route definition at above. Data which I want to pass to PeriodicDocumentsComponent can be a class or a string.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components

Comment: well thank you. I was using already data at routing the way I need was that :) @EliPorush