# How I can pass data with an event emitter in angular 17?

Tags: angular

I have two components in Angular one parent and one child and I need to pass data from child to parent with `@Output` and event emitter but I need to use the `<router-outlet>` in the parent template, not the specific selector `<child-component>`. How I can achieve this functionality?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components I think it's your case

Comment: I don't need simply passing the data but I need to create an event emitter in order to trigger an event method in parent class

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to use `@Output()`, use `service` and `BehaviorSubject` instead.