# How to pass data from one component to another in Angular using @Output and EventEmitter?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to pass uuid from login.component.ts which is generated after clicking the next button defined in login.component.html and use it in login-challenge.component.ts. I am using @Output and EventEmitter,but i am unable to do so..the problem is when i use `<app-login>` tag the entire html of login component is loaded ,but in majority of the solutions they are using the above deifned`<app-login>`tag and i dont want to use it

//login.component.ts

```
@Output() uuid = new EventEmitter<string>()

onSubmit() {
 if (this.loginForm.valid) {
   // this.isLoading = true
   this.authService.auth(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((data: User[]) => {
     this.dataSource = data
     // console.log(data)
     this.uuid.emit(`this is the sent data from login.... ${this.dataSource}`)
    /*  setTimeout(() => {
   },2000) */
   this.router.navigate([`/login-challenge`])
   }
   //include error message alert here-->
   /* ,
    (_e) => {
     alert("User Not Found! Please enter valid credentials.")
   } */
   )
 }
}
```

//login.component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="btn" (click)="onSubmit()">
      Next
    </button>
```

//login-challenge.component.ts

```
uuid! : string 
  receiveMessage($event: string) {
    this.uuid = $event;
    console.log("this.uuid :-", this.uuid)
  }
  
  onSubmit() {
    console.log("uuid from login component :- ",this.uuid)
    if(this.loginChallengeForm.valid){
      this.isLoading = true
      console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
      this.authService.challenge(this.loginChallengeForm.value).subscribe((token) =>{
        localStorage.setItem(this.tokenKey, token)
        console.log(token)
        alert("Verified User...now navigating!")
        const role = this.loginChallengeForm.value["userType"];
        if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
          console.log("Login done navigating to home");
          this.router.navigate([`${role}/home/dashboard`])
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

//login-challenge.component.html

```
<h2 (uuid)="receiveMessage($any($event))"></h2>
<h2>{{uuid}}</h2>
```

Comment: You can pass the data via the Angular Router, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36835123/5470544). `@Output` only works when you have a parent component that holds both the login and login-challenge component, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular `@Output()` decorator can only be used to pass on data from a child component to a parent component.

For example

Lets consider I have a component A

**a.component.html**

```
<h1>Hey I am from component A</h1>
<button (click)="buttonClicked()">Add</button>
```

**a.component.ts**

```
@component({selector: 'component-a'})
class ComponentA {
    data: Data= <some data>;
    @output() addButtonClick = new EventEmitter<Data>();

    buttonClicked(){
        this.addButtonClick.emit(data);
    }
}
```

Now lets consider Component B which is a parent of A

**b.component.html**

```
<component-a (addButtonClick)="addButtonClicked($event)"></component-a>
```

**b.component.ts**

```
@component()
class ComponentB {
    addButtonClicked(data: Data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Now as componentA is a child of componentB, the componentB can observe the @output() addButtonClick through event binding.

In your case, if the component are not in a parent child relationship you can use a service to achieve the expected functionality.

Create a service `login-handler` and add it as dependency in both `login.component` and `login-challenge.component`. Now in the login component emit the uuidSubject in the `login-handler.service` by calling emitUUID() method in `login-handler.service`. Now in the `login-challenge.component` subscribe to the `uuid$` in the `login-handler.service` and call the `onSubmit()`.

**login-handler.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginHandlerService {
    uuidSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
    uuid$: Observable<string> = uuidSubject.asObservable();

    emitUUID(uuid: string){
        this.uuidSubject.next(uuid);
    }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
@component()
class LoginComponent {
    public constructor(private readonly loginHandlerService: LoginHandlerService){}

    onSubmit() {
       if (this.loginForm.valid) {
   // this.isLoading = true
   this.authService.auth(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((data: User[]) => {
     this.dataSource = data
     // console.log(data)
     this.loginHandlerService.emitUUID(`this is the sent data from login.... ${this.dataSource}`)
    /*  setTimeout(() => {
   },2000) */
   this.router.navigate([`/login-challenge`])
   }
   //include error message alert here-->
   /* ,
    (_e) => {
     alert("User Not Found! Please enter valid credentials.")
   } */
   )
 }
    }
}
```

**login-challenge.component.ts**

```
@component()
class LoginChallengeComponent {
    public constructor(private readonly loginHandlerService: LoginHandlerService) {
        loginHandlerService.uuid$.subscribe(uuid => {
            this.onSubmit(uuid);
        })
    }

    onSubmit() {
       // your logic goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy I will try to integrate this ..your answer was insightful